# How do I install a package via npm on an offline computer?

Tags: node.js, npm, eos

I'd like to install an npm package (eosjs-ecc) onto an offline machine. I have access to an online machine where I can stage everything to be transferred to the offline machine. I can install the package on my online machine just fine (npm i eosjs-ecc) and grabs all the deps since it's online.

now how do i transfer the package so that when i sneakernet it to my offline machine, I can successfully install it with all of the dependencies as well.

Both my online and offline machines are running node (10.1) and npm (5.6).

Comment: Is everything on the 2 machines the same (OS, architecture, node/npm version, etc)?  Have you tried just zipping the project folder that includes `node_modules` and copying it to the offline machine?

Comment: both running fedora 27 64bit. when i copy the node_modules folder, where does it go on the offline machine? do i just place it wherever, then run npm install inside that directory?

Comment: Is this a [global](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) installation or a project local installation?  If it is global, it depends on where you tell npm to keep your global installs, if it is a project local install, put it in the project folder just like it would be on the online machine.

Comment: project local. so i copied over the node_modules and package-lock.json file into my project folder on the offline machine. running `npm ls` lists the package eosjs-ecc@4.0.0 and it's deps. then i run `node` and try to call it: `const ecc = require ('eosjs-ecc')` but results in an error that it cannot find the module 'eosjs-ecc'. does this mean the package didn't install correctly or it's not able to find it properly?